# Velocity Time graph

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity

I'm trying to help someone with their A level maths and I'm perplexed by this question.

> A car starts from rest at time $t=0\,\rm s$. It accelerates uniformly until its speed reaches $V\, \rm{m/s}$.
> It travels at constant speed for $12$ seconds and then decelerates uniformly,
> coming to rest when $t=26\,\rm s$.
> The total distance travelled by the car is $840 \,\rm m$. Find the value of $V$.

Here's my thoughts.
In a velocity time graph, the area under the curve is the distance traveled. The acceleration is uniform, so the graph is like a triangle, rectangle and another triangle. However, we are not told the value of time, say $t_1$,  at which the speed becomes V. So, I can't get beyond having two unknowns and just one equation.
The areas of the triangle, rectangle and triangle are $V(t_1/2)$,  $V(12-t_1)$, $7V$, and these sum to $840$. How can I eliminate $t_1$, or is this the wrong approach?